# signals in `c`. The use of while loop

Tags: c, signals

I'm trying to dive into the signals in C and trying to understand how it works. I understand that SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be handled/caught. My question is  could anyone explain what the role of `while-loop` in the below code? What if there wasn't a while-loop.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGUSR1)
        printf("received SIGUSR1\n");
    else if (signo == SIGKILL)
        printf("received SIGKILL\n");
    else if (signo == SIGSTOP)
        printf("received SIGSTOP\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    if (signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGUSR1\n");
    if (signal(SIGKILL, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGKILL\n");
    if (signal(SIGSTOP, sig_handler) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("\ncan't catch SIGSTOP\n");
    // A long long wait so that we can easily issue a signal to this process
    while(1) 
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you ran your program with the while() loop commented out, what happened?

Answer (score 2):

That while loop invokes `sleep(1)` forever.  Until it gets interrupted by a signal, at which point the process will stop sleeping, run the signal handler, then sleep again if/when the signal handler returns.

I would suggest changing it to `sleep(UINT_MAX)` inside the loop.  The program would have the same behavior but would be more efficient, since the code does not need to transition between user and kernel mode every second.

Comment: No, an interrupted `sleep` is not magically restarted! So some loop is needed around it. Hence you cannot replace `while(1) sleep(1);` with `sleep(UINT_MAX);`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Oh I get it now, this program wants to receive signals forever.  OK, I'll update my answer to be more reflective of what's happening in the OP's program.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>I am assuming you are on Linux or some POSIX system.</sup>

Then, read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html). Notice that a signal handler can only call async signal safe functions, and `printf` is *not* such a function. So your code has [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) so is very wrong.

Read POSIX documentation about [`<signal.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html). You may want to define a global `volatile sig_atomic_t flag;` and set it inside your signal handler (and test it outside, e.g. in some [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) above [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)).

Your

```
while(1) 
    sleep(1);
```

is simply an indefinite loop around the [sleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) function, waiting one second in the loop body (e.g. for a signal to be sent; that signal would "interrupt" the current call to `sleep`, but the loop will start again, unless the signal is terminating the process).

You could also use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) on your program to understand what system calls are involved.

BTW you could carefully loop on [sigsuspend(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) (instead of `sleep`).

I also suggest to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).